# analysis services datasource migrated

Tags: ssas

I have none experience with SSAS, I had this cube working perfectly…

The underlying tables that it was using were from a database, let’s call it ‘ABCD’. The problem is, that for other reasons ABCD database had to be split in ‘AB and ‘CD. Half the tables have been migrated to AB and the other half to CD. In my mind I want to open something as ALTER, edit the DB name, and everything would work as before, but SSAS is a bit of a black box for me; can I achieve this?

I know I can just access ABCD and create views to AB and CD and mask my problem, but I would really love to know how to modify the scripts that build the cube….

Comment: Are both AB and CD databases on the same server still?

Comment: Yes, same server. Just adding: some tables ended up in AB and others in CD

Comment: Can you just create views in AB that point to the tables which moved to CD? Otherwise you will need to edit the SSAS source code and make some tweaks

Comment: I want to edit the SSAS source, but I do not know where it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My recommendation is to just add views into the AB database which point to the tables which have moved to the CD database. Then you can edit the data source from Management Studio and point it to the AB database. (You just connect Object Explorer to Analysis Services, expand down to the database, expand to the Data Source, then double click to edit.)

If that's not an option then you can change the cube source code as follows...

I'm assuming it's a Multidimensional cube, not Tabular. If you already have Visual Studio and SSDT installed, great. Otherwise, install the [latest SSDT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?) which runs in Visual Studio 2015 as it's backwards compatible.

In SQL Server Management Studio, connect Object Explorer to Analysis Services and then right click on the database and choose Backup.

In Visual Studio, File... Open... Analysis Services Database. You are editing the cube "source code" live now. As soon as you save a change it will deploy it to the server.

Double click the data source and fix the connection string. Make sure it's using a version of the driver that's on the SSAS server. Point it to the AB database.

Then double click the DSV. In the tables list on the left, right click on each table which was moved to the CD database and choose Replace Table... With New Named Query. Click the "Switch to Generic Query Builder" button and then edit the query to look something like:

select *
from CD.dbo.YourTable

Click Save.

Then go back to Management Studio, right click the database and choose Process. Do a Full Process on the database. It should succeed and be up to date.

It is possible to reverse engineer a deployed SSAS database. The above assumes that's not important to you. But if you need to do this, in Visual Studio do File... New Project... Templates... Business Intelligence... Analysis Services... Import From Server (Multidimensional and Data Mining).

Comment: “In SQL Server Management Studio, connect Object Explorer to Analysis Services and then right click on the database and choose Backup.” Great, I backed it up to another drive L:.

“In Visual Studio, File... Open... Analysis Services Database. You are editing the cube "source code" live now. As soon as you save a change it will deploy it to the server.” How come if I make a change it will deploy to the server, if what I opened is just a back located in a different drive?!

Comment: @Chicago1988 I don't follow. Those instructions let you edit the deployed SSAS database directly. If anything goes wrong then you can restore from backup. Is that what you are asking?